# OpenSSH client works, but Putty can only receive data

Tags: ssh, putty, terminal

There is an application with a custom SSH interface that authenticates then launches a command line utility. It works as expected using OpenSSH's Client:

```
Login Prompt -> 
Username/pass <- 
Main Menu ->
Menu Select <-
Other Menu Opts ->
-> = To Client
<- = To SSH Server
```

However with Putty, no data is sent after the Username and Password

```
Login Prompt -> 
Username/pass <- 
Main Menu ->
Menu Select -X (no data sent)
-> = To Client
<- = To SSH Server
```

What setting in Putty could lead to this behavior? Do you believe it is a terminal setting or an SSH setting? Does the server need to respond to a special SSH Req?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the the SSH Server not responding to OOB SSH Requests. OpenSSH doesn't care about this, Putty will not send data unless it gets response.